# failed to truncate 00manifest.d

Tags: mercurial

I was trying to undo my last commit and enabled the mq extension, but the `hg strip` command failed and now I can't commit:

```
basin@BASIN /cygdrive/c/progs/maven/nb/releases-modresource_cache_root/lib.cvsclient
$ hg strip -r . --keep
saved backup bundle to /cygdrive/c/progs/maven/nb/releases-modresource_cache_root/.hg/strip-backup/ac19a716fbf9-6b28e0c3-backup.hg
transaction abort!
failed to truncate 00manifest.d
rollback failed - please run hg recover
strip failed, backup bundle stored in '/cygdrive/c/progs/maven/nb/releases-modresource_cache_root/.hg/strip-backup/ac19a716fbf9-6b28e0c3-backup.hg'
abort: Invalid argument

basin@BASIN /cygdrive/c/progs/maven/nb/releases-modresource_cache_root/lib.cvsclient
$ hg recover
rolling back interrupted transaction
failed to truncate 00manifest.d
abort: Invalid argument

$ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.3.2)
(see https://mercurial-scm.org for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2017 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Is it possible to manually cleanup the failed transaction?

Upd:

```
$ hg verify
abandoned transaction found - run hg recover
checking changesets
checking manifests
 manifest@?: data length off by -1958844 bytes
 manifest@?: rev 310321 points to nonexistent changeset 316448
 manifest@?: 14b8e332323c not in changesets
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
 applemenu/src/org/netbeans/modules/applemenu/layer.xml@?: rev 12 points to unexpected changeset 149753
 (expected 149755)
 defaults/src/org/netbeans/modules/defaults/Eclipse-keybindings-mac.xml@?: rev 0 points to unexpected changeset 149753
 (expected 149755)
 defaults/src/org/netbeans/modules/defaults/Eclipse-keybindings.xml@?: rev 25 points to unexpected changeset 149753
 (expected 149755)
 defaults/src/org/netbeans/modules/defaults/mf-layer.xml@?: rev 74 points to unexpected changeset 149753
 (expected 149755)
 lib.cvsclient/src/org/netbeans/lib/cvsclient/util/LoggedDataInputStream.java@?: rev 5 points to nonexistent changeset 316448
 (expected )
 lib.cvsclient/src/org/netbeans/lib/cvsclient/util/LoggedDataInputStream.java@?: 7ad471280c10 not in manifests
warning: orphan revlog 'data/lib.cvsclient/src/org/netbeans/lib/cvsclient/util/InterruptibleInputStream.java.i'
194663 files, 316448 changesets, 1130994 total revisions
6 warnings encountered!
9 integrity errors encountered!
```

Comment: Does `hg pull /cygdrive/c/progs/maven/nb/releases-modresource_cache_root/.hg/strip-backup/ac19a716fbf9-6b28e0c3-backup.hg` work?

Comment: @ngoldbaum `pulling from ...hg/searching for changes/no changes found
`

Comment: What does `hg verify` say? Also there is a page in the wiki describing some strategies to recover:  https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption

Comment: @Rudi updated..

Comment: This looks bad. I would try to start over with a fresh clone, update to the same revision as your damaged WC, delete the checked out files in the new WC and copy the files outside the .hg directory into the fresh WC. And you should report this bug at https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Don't work on a shared drive.  Shared drives have complicated permissions issues.

Option 2: If you must work on a shared drive, dig into "how to set and change permissions".  Make sure that *you* have *all* permissions on the shared-drive files in question.